# MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'The property '_ts' of type

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest

I am getting the error from the BSONelement for the below model

```
"   [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Version")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public long Version => Convert.ToInt64(Date.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));

    [BsonElement("_ts")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public long _ts => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

    [BsonElement(elementName: "_ts")]
    public long _ts1 { get; set; }"
```

both _ts for different.
_ts is used for insert collection to mongo db
_ts1 is used to get the records from mongo db. both are used by different project.
How we achieve with out breaking existing structure.

Thanks in advance